# C Pointer arithmetic to fill struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am currently trying to fill a struct like this

```
typedef struct
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int hour;
    int minute;
} tDateTime;

typedef struct sFlight
{
    char code[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    char arrival[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    char departure[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    int availableSeats;
    tDateTime dateTime;
    struct sFlight * nextFlight;
} tFlight;
```

Reading from a txt file. This is what I am currently doing

```
void ops_loadFlightsInformation(tFlight * firstFlight)
{   
    // Open the file with r to only read
    FILE *file = fopen(OPS_FLIGHTS_FILE, "r");
    // If file is not open return
    if(file == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    tFlight currentFlight;

    // Loop until there are no flights
    while(next != 0) {
        strcpy(currentFlight.code, helpers_scanFromFile(file, MAX_NAME_LENGTH));
        strcpy(currentFlight.departure, helpers_scanFromFile(file, MAX_NAME_LENGTH));
        strcpy(currentFlight.arrival, helpers_scanFromFile(file, MAX_NAME_LENGTH));
        fscanf(file, "%d\n", &currentFlight.availableSeats);
        fscanf(file, "%d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d\n", &currentFlight.dateTime.year, &currentFlight.dateTime.month, &currentFlight.dateTime.day, &currentFlight.dateTime.hour, &currentFlight.dateTime.minute);
        fscanf(file, "%d\n", &next);

        printf("%s \n", currentFlight.code);
    }

    printf("%s \n", firstFlight->code);

    // Close the file handle
    fclose(file);
}
```

I cant manage to think how to fill the struct pointers on the while loop. I tried different ways but I always end up with the

```
warning: X may be used uninitialized in this function
```

Or just editing the same pointer over and over so only editing the first element. The loop works fine currentFlight gets populated correctly but I dont know how to translate it to firstFlight struct and ->nextFlight pointers

Comment: There isn't a variable X in your code; what was the actual message and the line number and the variable.

Comment: You have a design problem.  Your function can fail but there's no way for the calling code to know that it has failed.  That's bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to read the flights and put them in a list. So before reading the next flight, allocate a new piece of memory and put it in `next`. Then use pointer notation to address the members:

```
void ops_loadFlightsInformation(tFlight * firstFlight)
{   
    // Open the file with r to only read
    FILE *file = fopen(OPS_FLIGHTS_FILE, "r");
    // If file is not open return
    if(file == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    tFlight *currentFlight = firstFlight;

    // Loop until there are no flights
    while(!feof(file)) {
        currentFlight->next= malloc(sizeof(tFlight));
        currentFlight= currentFlight->next;
        strcpy(currentFlight->code, helpers_scanFromFile(file, MAX_NAME_LENGTH));
        strcpy(currentFlight->departure, helpers_scanFromFile(file, MAX_NAME_LENGTH));
        strcpy(currentFlight->arrival, helpers_scanFromFile(file, MAX_NAME_LENGTH));
        fscanf(file, "%d\n", &currentFlight->availableSeats);
        fscanf(file, "%d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d\n", &currentFlight->dateTime.year, &currentFlight->dateTime.month, &currentFlight->dateTime.day, &currentFlight->dateTime.hour, &currentFlight->dateTime.minute);
        //fscanf(file, "%d\n", &next);  // what is this?????

        printf("%s \n", currentFlight->code);
    }

    printf("%s \n", firstFlight->code);

    // Close the file handle
    fclose(file);
}
```

(note: check code on `scanf` and `malloc` should be added. Assumes your helpers are correct and always read the strings. Assumes the file contains at least one flight.)